# Writing an R function to go over characters to calculate a score

Tags: r, loops, character

I have a data set with three variables. Company names (there are six companies), Element Score Name (has three levels: Met, Not Met, Not Applicable) and Status (has three levels: No Change, Changed, Unsure). A company is assessed on six indicators. The company name, Element Score Name and Status is logged per row, meaning that the data consists of 36 rows. As an example of the type of data I am working on:

```
  df <- data.frame(
  company = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), each = 6),
  element_score = sample(c("Met", "Not Met", "Not Applicable"), size = 36, replace = TRUE),
  status = sample(c("No Change", "Changed", "Unsure"), size = 36, replace = TRUE)
)
```

I want to write a function such that that a company receives 2/6 points if the Element Score Name variable is Met and Status is No Change in a particular row. Similarly, I want to add points if Element Score Name is Unmet but the Status is Changed. Finally, I do not want to add points if Element Score Variable is Not Met or Not Applicable and the Status is No Change. I tried this, but it does not work:

```
  # Create function to calculate scores
  calculate_score <- function(data) {
  # Create data frame to hold scores
  scores <- data.frame(company = unique(data$company), score = 0)
  # Loop over companies
  for (i in 1:nrow(scores)) {
    # Get data for current company
    company_data <- data[data$company == scores$company[i], ]
    # Calculate score for current company
    score <- sum(
      ifelse(company_data$element_score == "Met" & company_data$status == "No Change", 1, 0),
      ifelse(company_data$element_score == "Not Met" & company_data$status == "Changed", 1, 0)
    )
    # Add score to scores data frame
    scores$score[i] <- score
  }
  # Return scores data frame
  return(scores)
}

# Calculate scores for example data set
calculate_score(df)
```

I get several errors in the end and the code is not running.

Comment: I did not get any errors reproducing your source code. what error message did you get?

Comment: Ditto with no errors, R 4.2.2, aarch64.

Comment: agree, it appears to work.. although the function could be changed to a single line: `f <- \(e,s) sum(sum(e=="Met" & s=="No Change"),sum(e=="Not Met" & s=="Changed"))`, and then just apply `f` by group: `reframe(df, score = f(element_score, status), .by=company)`